# Global class variable vs pointer in c++

Tags: c++

Lets assume I have the following class:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
};
```

I need to declare a global instance of class `A` (required by spec.), what works better?

```
A a; // is the constructor even called here?
```

or

```
A* pa; // and allocate later a new instance
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done any tests? Why wouldn't the constructor be called when it's declared there? Also why are you creating globals like this instead of a more formally declared singleton?

Comment: Global instances are evil, just saying ...

Comment: @tadman thanks for your reply, this is homework and singletons are not covered. i tried to print something in the constructor but it didn't do anything whereas using the instance seems to work.

Comment: @userfault singletons are just glorified global variables - they are just as evil.

Comment: i tried again, this time it did print... i must have got something wrong the last time.
so i guess the question comes down to global instance vs. global pointer ?
thanks

Comment: Knowing now that this is homework, and the end goal is a grade - both approaches should help you achieve your goal.

Comment: @JesperJuhl They're at least on a leash. Pure globals are nothing but anarchy.

Comment: nothing is better but each has its use

Comment: @tadman, Perhaps because one instance isn't appropriate? Just look at `std::cout`. You can have your own instances of `std::ostream`.

Comment: @tadman as far as I'm concerned, they are completely equal. A singleton provides *no* benefits over a global - if you disagree, please provide examples.

Comment: @chris That's at least in the `std` namespace, so it's contained, though a case could be made that exposing `cout` as a global is a bad idea. It's far from an ideal way to express these things.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If you're giving access to a singleton via a method then you can lazy-initialize them which means they may not need to be constructed. It's also possible for that method to decide to hand out the same instance, or later to hand out different ones (e.g. per thread) if necessary. A global variable is, always, just a dumb variable. In any case, I think `std::cout` or `My::singleton` is better than traditional global variable cruft like `a` as we have in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Global variable as pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18429391/3425536)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A a; - is the constructor even called here?" - yes, the constructor is called.

"* pa; - and allocate later a new instance" - if you actually assign something to this pointer variable before using it, then it can work. But do you?

In general I'd say that the need for global variables indicate a flaw in the design. But if you really have to have them, then make sure they are constructed before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

If `A a` is used, there would not be a need to release memory allocated to a. When the main() function exits, the destructor for A will be automatically called.

If `A *pa` is used, ideally pa should be explicitly deleted at some point in the code with `delete pa` and care should be taken to not use `pa` after it has been deleted.